# How to initialize structure pointers in a structure?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
typedef struct cpu{
    process_t** cpu;
    int cpu_id;
    int queue_len;
}cpu_t;
```

If I want to initialize this struct:

```
cpu_t** cpus = malloc(sizeof(cpu_t*)*num_processors);

int i = 0;



for(i=0;i<num_processors;i++){
    cpus[i]->cpu_id = i;

    cpus[i]->queue_len = 0;
    
    cpus[i]->cpu = malloc(sizeof(process_t*)*num_process);
    
    printf("test\n");
}
```

The "test" will not appear and my program seems to stop after this.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including complete source code that can be compiled and executed.

Comment: You need `cpus[i] = malloc(sizeof(cpu_t));` before accessing any field in `cpu[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

You allocated an array of uninitialized pointers

```
cpu_t** cpus = malloc(sizeof(cpu_t*)*num_processors);
```

Thus the subscript operator returns such an uninitialized pointer as for example in this statement

```
cpus[i]->cpu_id = i;
```

and using such a pointer to access memory invokes undefined behavior.

Maybe actually you need something like the following

```
cpu_t *cpus = malloc( sizeof( cpu_t ) );

cpus->cpu = malloc( sizeof( process_t * ) * num_process );
//...
```

Pay attention to that using the same name `cpu` for different entities as in this structure definition

```
typedef struct cpu{
    process_t** cpu;
    //..
```

only confuses readers of the code.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
cpu_t** cpus = malloc(sizeof(cpu_t*)*num_processors);
```

You're allocating space for an array of pointers to `cpu_t`.  These pointers have not been initialized, however.  Then later you attempt to dereference these pointers:

```
cpus[i]->cpu_id = i;
```

Dereferencing an uninialized pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It seems that you don't actually want an array of pointers to `cpu_t`, but an array of `cput_t`.  You can create such an array like this:

```
cpu_t *cpus = malloc(sizeof(cpu_t)*num_processors);
```

Then you can access each array element using `.` instead of `->`.  You'll want to make a similar change to the `cpu` member of `cpu_t` to create an array of those:

```
typedef struct cpu{
    process_t *cpu;
    int cpu_id;
    int queue_len;
}cpu_t;

...

for(i=0;i<num_processors;i++){
    cpus[i].cpu_id = i;
    cpus[i].queue_len = 0;
    cpus[i].cpu = malloc(sizeof(process_t)*num_process);
}
```